# Facing an error while installing riscv-tests - riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc: fatal error: cannot execute 'cc1'

Tags: riscv

I am trying to install the riscv-tests folder using the following steps:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/riscv/riscv-tests
$ cd riscv-tests
$ git submodule update --init --recursive
$ autoconf
$ ./configure --prefix=$RISCV/target
$ make
$ make install
```

I am getting the following error while giving the 'make' command:

> riscv64-unknown-elf-gcc: fatal error: cannot execute 'cc1':execvp: No such file or directory

[image]

I tried installing the the package 'gcc-riscv64-unknown-elf'. But still the error is showing up.

Comment: did you try installing `build-essential`

Comment: Yes I did, still it gives this error.

Comment: Have you built and installed the [toolchain](https://github.com/riscv-collab/riscv-gnu-toolchain) ?

Comment: Yes, cc1 is present inside the toolchain too. When I gave the find command, it gives me the path of cc1.